# GAM with Beta-Binomial family on very large data

Tags: generalized-additive-model, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a GAM on (success) counts assuming they follow a beta-binomial distribution. Each data point has three values:
1- Number of trials (N)
2- Number of successes (n)
3- A covariate (p) which determines the parameters of the beta-binomial

At first, I thought about using `mgcv` package in R. However, that package does not support beta-binomial family. Instead, I found the `gamlss` package with beta-binomial support. Here is the code I am using:

```
y <- cbind(df$n, df$N - df$n)
model <- gamlss(y ~ cs(p), family=BB, data=df))
```

However, the problem is I have a very large data (`df` has about 2M rows). Is there anyway I could speed up the fitting? It currently takes about 3 hours. `mgcv` package has a method (`bam`) specifically meant for large data sets. When I use `bam` with binomial family, it fits the model in 2 minutes. But unfortunately, I need beta-binomial family so I cannot use `bam`. Appreciate any suggestion/pointers how to speed this up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

model <- gamlss(y ~ pb(p), fmily=BB, data=df)

where pb() fits a P-spline and automatically chooses the degrees of freedom using local ML.

The problem with cs() is that it fits a cubic spline
and uses a default extra 3 degrees of freedom for smoothing
(on top of the linear term) which may not be appropriate
for your data.

Also the default starting values for mu and sigma may not be suitable for your data.
You could try fitting a simpler model,
e.g. constants, linear or polynomial for each of mu and sigma,
and using that fitted model (say m1) as starting values for mu and sigma using argument,
start.from=m1

Also note that you are only modelling the mu parameter of
BB(n, mu, sigma).
You can also model the sigma parameter e.g. using argument

sigma.fo =~ pb(p)

although this will be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Other ideas for speeding up the gamlss fit:

1. Change the convergence criterion (c.crit) for the Global Deviance (i.e. 2 * fitted log likelihood) used for convergence of the gamlss iterations.
   The default, c.crit=0.001, is very small.
   You could change this to 0.1 or even 0.5 using argument, e.g.
   c.crit=0.1
   (the resulting change in Global Deviance per case is  minuscule for 2 million, 2M, cases).

2. Change the default maximum number of gamlss iterations (n.cyc).
   By default n.cyc=20.
   However occasionally when fitting a model, the Global Deviance stabilises, but then jitters slightly around, so you could stop the fitting when the Global Deviance stabilises, using argument, e.g.
   n.cyc=10
3. You could randomly sample say 100,000 cases (in data frame df2) from the 2M.
   It is likely that the fit (say model2) will be very little different using the reduced sample size (especially with just one explanatory variable).

However if you wish to check this you could use the fitted model2 to find starting values for the full 2M fit, by

model2 <- gamlss(y ~ pb(p), family=BB, data=df2)

df$mu1 <- predict(model2, what=“mu”, newdata=df)

df$sigma1 <- predict(model2, what=“sigma”, newdata=df)

model1 <-  gamlss(y ~ pb(p), family=BB, data=df, mu.start=mu1, sigma.start=sigma1)

You could also include the argument  c.crit=0.1.

Please let us know if any of the above help
[especially 3) above, if you try it].

[Note the above model only fits a model for mu, with a constant for sigma.
You can also include a model for sigma by argument
sigma.fo =~ pb(p) ]